# ImageJ - can not read out string from Results table after it has been saved

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I'm writing a macro that creates a results table that looks like this:

> **Name     value1     value2**
>   string1    number     number
>   string2    number     number

At this point, if I use the getResultString("Name", 0) command in a loop I get the desired result (string1).
However, I need to save the table and re-open it at a later point.

If I save the Results table, close it and import it as a Results table, getResultString("Name", 0) gives me "Null" as an answer.
I tried saving it as .txt, .csv, or .xls files but the problem persists.

The re-imported table looks the same, but for some reason getResultString doesn't seem to work.

Any pointers? Workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you observed is a bug. I was able to reproduce it using the following macro:

```bs
row = nResults;
dir = getDirectory("temp");

setResult("String", row, "xyz");
setResult("Number", row, 5.0);

// get results from new table
print(getResultString("String", 0));
print(getResult("Number", 0));

saveAs("Results", dir + "Results.xls");
open(dir + "Results.xls");

// get results from re-opened table
print(getResultString("String", 0));
print(getResult("Number", 0));
```

I filed a [bug report](http://fiji.sc/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1157), please also read [how to best report bugs](http://imagej.net/Bug_reporting_best_practices) in ImageJ.

**UPDATE**: the [bug](http://fiji.sc/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1157) was fixed by Wayne Rasband in [ImageJ 1.50c8](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/commit/bc315d3) with the comment:

> Note that the bug only occurs when the first column is non-numeric and
>   all other columns are numeric.